# What is the correct way to wire a 3 way switch where power comes into the middle switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, multiway-switch

I found two books and neither had the diagram. Only I found two separate diagrams that did not work.

The setup:

- Box 1 with 3 wire runs to box 2.
- Box 2 has 2 wire power in, 2 wire to light and 3 wire to box 1

Both diagrams show Power (Black) to 3 wire (black), connected to common black screw in box 1 switch.

Power in Neutral (white) to light neutral (white/silver screw)

Box 2 switch Common black screw to  Light (black/ brass screw)

Where they differ is in the Red and White from the 3 wire.  One shows reds on left, whites on right; both switches. The other shows Red left box 2, red right box 1; white right box 2, white left box 1.

Both configurations trip the breaker.

I have checked ground connections, lines with multimeter, 3 separate switches, Checked tension and for micro holes/pinching, and checked the light.
The issue seems to be with the 3 way wiring.

I'm at a loss.

This is the diagram of what i tried, the other diagram was the same with the red and white in the far right box swapped... that didn't work either.

[image: This Isn't working]

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of your boxes?

Comment: I can not at this time, at fathers shop and I wont be back there for a few days. He may be able to send me couple pictures tomorrow.

Comment: @BillWeckel: The diagram is correct, if those switches are drawn with the common terminal at the upper left. - Unfortunately some switches are made with the common terminal across from the travelers, i.e.at the lower right in this drawing.

Comment: Actually, now that I've looked at the diagram again, it is correct... They're using the white wire from the 12/3 as a traveler... @A.I.Breveleri I deleted my previous comment. I looked at the diagram a little closer the second time. Unfortunately, I posted my new comment only seconds after yours...

Comment: if you look close you can see the top left screw is black on both switches in the diagram indicating the common... Still didn't work though.

Comment: What kind of light fixture do you have? Do you have a multimeter?

Comment: its a standard el cheapo socket 2 silver 2 brass e27.  I do have a multi yes

Comment: That's really weird that this drawing uses a yellow line for the ground wire instead of green. Maybe it's to represent bare copper, but still...

Comment: i took it as a copper

Comment: Please post your update as an answer and I'll give it a +1

Comment: Please don't edit the title with `[Answered]`. Instead, post an answer that indicates what the problem was or accept one of the other answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was the roof sheeters and my father (by side stapling the wire instead of top) messed it up:

[image: electrical wire shorted by roofing nails]

All answers given and even the initial diagram are right, Harper's is the easiest to understand.

Comment: Your father did it correctly. The roofer screwed up. Wiring only needs a guard plate if it will be within 1-3/4" of the finish surface **which means, running it down the center of 2x4s is correct**.  People sticking things in surfaces are expected to use fasteners <= 1-3/4", or be responsible for the consequences.   If they needed that much adhesion they needed screws not longer nails.

Answer (score 9):

You'll lose your mind dealing with all the red black white business.  **Get a 5-pack of colored electrical tape** and start marking wires for their *actual function*.  Always mark wires the same at both ends.  Here is what's really happening in a 3-way.

[image]

First, the two **traveler wires** get marked yellow.  There is no need to tell them from each other.    So in the /3 cable, tape the black and white wires with yellow tape.  That'll leave red, which is a preferential color for **switched-hot**.

On the black and white cable up to the lamp, mark both ends of the black wire with red tape, since it is switched hot.  Mark the lamp's black lead red also.

---

*The hard part is behind us. Now we wrap up.*

---

On both 3-way switches, the yellow wires go on the *brass* screws.

On the near 3-way, the supply wire (black) goes onto the *black* common screw.  (It's almost like someone color coded it, lol).

On the far 3-way, you have no choice: 1 wire 1 screw.  Done.

All the wires that remain are white and red.  Nut them by color: white to white, red to red.

*Golly, that was easy!  Or rather, we made it easy with our thinking cap and some colored tape.*

Comment: Isn't that the same as show in the diagram with the exception being connecting power in the close switch  rather than box with only 3 wire? Are you also saying that travelers need not both be left or both be right?

Comment: @beast yeah, you could do it that way too mark the red and white "yellow" and land the lamp switched-hot on the common screw.  Six of one, half dozen of the other, though I like mine slightly more because it removes always-hot from the right switch, and thus the temptation to extend that circuit onward by bootlegging ground.  My thesis is more about "mark with colors, don't lose your mind".

Comment: so the travelers are interchangeable? both ends could be connected to either location?

Comment: @beast yes, if you swap travelers, it does nothing important. Edited. It changes switch phase, which is only a problem if you have OCD.  Sue me... I like "both switches down" to be "off", so if it's not, I either swap travelers or just flip the switch over in the box.

Comment: Marking like this solves the problem I fully agree.+

Comment: @beast: With mechanical switches, swapping travelers will swap which combinations of switch handle positions represent "on" and "off".  Some "smart switches", however, need to have labeled travelers which are connected in a known fashion at each end.  For example, to handle a scenario where a two travelers and neutral are sent to a box with a 3-way switch, from which the switch common and the supplied neutral would then be fed to a lamp, some smart switches have a "remote sender" in the upstream box send unswitched hot and a control output through the wires that had served as travelers, ...

Comment: ...and have the actual smart switch in the downstream box receive the unswitched hot and control signal, and then make or break a connection between the unswitched hot and the lamp.  Such an arrangement wouldn't work if the travelers were swapped, so labeling them distinctly would help facilitate any future upgrades to such arrangements.

Comment: @supercat those aren't really travelers then... one is a datacomm line and the other is hot or neutral.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica: Yes, but my point is that the switches are designed to easily retrofit into existing wiring that is set up with travelers, but they use the two wires for different purposes and will only function correctly if they are wired in the required orientation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best diagram I can come up with without doing a Google search... Hopefully you can understand it...
[image: 3 way switch diagram]

Since your incoming power and switch leg are in the same box we have to send power to the farthest switch ( switch #2 ), which we do with the white wire from the 12/3. This will energize the travelers, the black and red wires from the 12/3. We then attach the black wire from the fixture to the black screw on switch #1. Wire nut the white wire from your incoming power to the white wire running to the fixture. Circuit complete. Obviously, make sure your ground wires are wire nutted as well...

Comment: OK, so this is again basically what i did, i just kept my black black and marked both ends of white with black tape.  Has to be a faulty switch then?

Comment: It's a possibility. It's hard for me to say it's the switch without me physically putting eyes on the circuit wiring. Someone else may be willing to confirm your suspicions tho... Pics of your boxes would definitely help.

Comment: Yeah, ill get my father to send some as soon as he can. That failing i go out again thur or fri. i mean i checked and rechecked the wireing, i am certain it is as the diagram i posted shows... so if thats corect its not the wiring

Answer (score 1):

Start with a good generic drawing like in the Harper Answer. Then imagine each wire is a stretchable elastic. Move each device around to where you want it, while maintaining the integrity of the "elastics."
Then re-draw the drawing as wires in each cable. Add your junction boxes and grounds. Now you have a working drawing

Answer (score 0):

For what it’s worth, I just relocated power from one switch in the three way to the other.

Just had to re identify some white neutrals and land the new hot wires. Hope that helps

Comment: Please note that this site does not run as a discussion forum, its question and answers.  And this is not ananswer.